# jQuery Flexigrid with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, flexigrid

I' trying to use Flexigrid with ASP.NET MVC. I need all the JSON type functionality(searching, sorting, find) except that I'm using foreach in my view and looping to generate the table rows.

```
<table id="gllisting">
            <% foreach (var item in Model)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.GLCODE) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.DESCRIPT) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.PL_BS) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.LOCCODE) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.SUBLEDGER) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.SALUTATION) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= Html.Encode(item.DEPARTMENT) %>
                </td>
             </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
```

Now I using a script block like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gllisting").flexigrid({
        colModel: [
                { display: "Ledger Code", name: "glcode", width: 40, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Description", name: "name", width: 180, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Account Type", name: "ac_type", width: 120, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Cash/Bank Code", name: "loccode", width: 130, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Subledger", name: "subledgr", width: 80, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Salutation", name: "salutation", width: 80, sortable: true, align: "left" },
                { display: "Department", name: "depmas", width: 80, sortable: true, align: "left" }],
        buttons: [
                { name: "Add", bclass: "add", onpress: test },
                { name: "Delete", bclass: "delete", onpress: test },
                { separator: true}],
        searchitems: [
                { display: "Ledger Code", name: "glcode" },
                { display: "Description", name: "name", isdefault: true}],
        sortname: "glcode",
        sortorder: "asc",
        usepager: true,
        title: "General Ledger Listing",
        useRp: true,
        rp: 15,
        showTableToggleBtn: true,
        width: 700,
        height: 500
    });
});
```

Its not working please help. I'm unable to use flexigrid. I'm using jQuery version 1.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fallback to an older version of jQuery, like version 1.3. I think it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need 2 more parameters:
url: '/Controller/Action',
dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be old question, but I see it as related to mine, so I can confirm that the second reply is correct. Your JavaScript needs to look like

```
$("#flexClients").flexigrid({
    url: '/Client/Client/',
    dataType: 'json',
    colModel: [
    { display: 'Client Id', name: 'Id', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center', hide: true },
    { display: 'Client #', name: 'Number', width: 100, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
    { display: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 350, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
    { display: 'Contact 1', name: 'Contact1', width: 350, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
    ],
```

So, you're missing url and dataType